# ООП. Наследование

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, pyqt5, наследование

Пытаюсь некоторую функциональность вынести в другой класс и затем унаследоваться от него:

```
class Buts():
    def __init__(self):
        self.row = 0
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.up)

    def up(self):
        print('up')

class MyWindow(QMainWindow, Buts):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        uic.loadUi("form.ui", self)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Получаю ошибку:
AttributeError: 'MyWindow' object has no attribute 'pushButton'

Comment: Странная идея, по мне так :) Да и кнопка у вас скорее всего в `uic.loadUi("form.ui", self)` создается, а обращаетесь к ней в конструкторе, т.е. сначала вы обращаетесь к кнопке, а после создаете кнопку. Вот и получаете ошибку

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Когда вы вызываете `super().__init__()`, происходит вызов `__init__` у базовых классов.

Например в этот момент вызывается реализация `__init__` в `Buts`, но кнопка была создана после, через `uic.loadUi("form.ui", self)`, вот и получаете ошибку.

Можно попробовать обойти, тем чтобы поменять порядок вызова - сначала создание виджетов, а после вызов `super().__init__()`.

Запускаемый минипример:

```
from PyQt5.Qt import QMainWindow, QApplication, QPushButton


class Buts:
    def __init__(self):
        self.row = 0
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.up)

    def up(self):
        print('up')

class MyWindow(QMainWindow, Buts):
    def __init__(self):
        # uic.loadUi("form.ui", self)
        self.pushButton = QPushButton()

        super().__init__()

        self.setCentralWidget(self.pushButton)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

А так, лучше сделать метод `initUI` у `Buts` и в нем обращаться к виджетам, а сам метод вызывать в MyWindow после `super().__init__()` и `uic.loadUi("form.ui", self)`:

```
class Buts:
    def __init__(self):
        self.row = 0
    
    def initUI(self):
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.up)

    def up(self):
        print('up')

class MyWindow(QMainWindow, Buts):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        uic.loadUi("form.ui", self)

        self.initUI()
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Получилось